# Dynamic web page convertible to PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm thinking about writing a professional CV page that would be easy to update, using a simple backend to add informations and blocks of optional details, and... (feature creap coming)

Anyway, I was thinking of a "simple" web page grpahically, that would easily be convertible to  PDF file, using browser functionallity or not.

Assuming that the page have blocks of text that you must ckick a button to see (those are optional details), what should I know or what tools should I use to write this web page?

I'm totally rusted on web code, I used php without ajax a lot before but I understand the idea. I was thinking maybe it would be a good opportunity to try a framework to make a "webapp", like Ruby+ROR or Python+Django? Is that a good idea? I'm ready to learn about those, I'm just not sure if it's worth for such project.

Should I know some things about html code or javascript behaviour that I shouldn't use because it would break any PDF generation tool or something like that?

Any advice on the way to proceed would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read up on how to create a [print stylesheet](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets). This way when you go to print the CV you can choose something like [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp) and your print stylesheet will automatically be used. You will make your stylesheet show all hidden text blocks and hide things like navigation, buttons, etc.

I can't tell you whether or not it's worth it for you to try a new framework for this project, that's up to you. It's not bad to learn new things. Since I don't know all the details of your project it's hard to answer if it's worth it for this particular project. From your description is sounds like you're just making an HTML resume/CV which sound, to me, like one flat HTML page with some JavaScript. If that's the case you could probably just use a text editor.

If you want my personal opinion, ASP.Net 4 is the way to go if you want to learn something new (or if you just want to use a great framework).

As far as breaking the PDF generation, your print stylesheet will be responsible for showing/hiding things but any JavaScripts should be aware of this as well. Check the link I gave you above for more information.

Comment: +1 : Thanks, that's helpful. About the project itself, there would be a separate backend page to add/remove blocks. I want to automatize the page code generation to avoid hasty copy/paste errors in the future. So it apparently require at least a bit of php. I think I'll try RoR anyway, so don't bother with this part of this question.